# playing audio with javascript using the links from csv file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv

I am trying to make a basic page where if you click on the alphabet, it will play the sound file of the pronunciation.

I am using [csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmuNv.png) that looks like this. 
When the button is clicked it does play an audio file, but only the first audio file regardless of which button I press.

Would anyone have a solution for this?

Here is the current js.

```js
$(function() {
  //Load the data
  d3.csv("alphabet-sound-files.csv").then(function(data) {
    // Write the data variable to the console ->
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data[0].audioFiles);

    //Process the data here
    var content = document.getElementById("contents-alphabet");
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

      // create div with class "alphabet-sound"
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.className = "alphabet-sound";
      content.appendChild(div);

      //make a button with each tof the alphabet (letters)
      var button = document.createElement("button");
      button.className = "click-for-sound";
      var list = document.getElementsByClassName("click-for-sound");
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].setAttribute("id", +i);
      }

      var letters = document.createTextNode(data[i]['alphabet']);

      //store audio sources

      //create links
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = data[i]['audioFiles'];

      div.appendChild(a); // put a inside the div
      //div.appendChild(audio);
      div.appendChild(button); // put button inside the div
      button.appendChild(letters); // put each letter in the button


      $(document).ready(function() {

        var audio = document.createElement("audio");
        audio.className = "pronunciation";
        var list = document.getElementsByClassName("pronunciation");
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
          list[i].setAttribute("id", +i);
        }
        audio.src = data[i]['audioFiles'];


        $(document).on('click', ".click-for-sound", function() {

          audio.play();

        });
      });


    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do the following:

1. Remove the inner loops on lines 20-23 and lines 43-46. Those lines are bugger for various reasons, the most important being: you're using the same variable (`i`) for all your loops (including these nested loops), your code is breaking. Use something other than `i` for your inner loop variables.
2. Use `const`, or an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to deal with the variable hoisting issues you're experiencing with line 52.

```
const audio = document.createElement("audio");
```

3. Line 50 won't work because the selector is wrong (it will select all the button elements, when you only want to select the button you created in line 18). However, you didn't need to reselect the button element because you already had a reference to it from line 18.

```
    $(button).on("click", function () { audio.play(); });
```

Example working code:

```
d3.csv("alphabet-sound-files.csv").then(function (data) {

var content = document.getElementById("contents-alphabet");
//Process the data here
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // Create a local variable for the current audioFile, simplifies the code below a lot.
    var audioFile = data[i];

    // create div class "alphabet-sound" as before
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "alphabet-sound";
    content.appendChild(div);

    //store audio sources

    // Create audio tag before button.
    const audio = document.createElement("audio");
    // Use of const avoids issues with hoisting 

    // all elements should have unique ids. Therefore, prefix audio elements with audio1, audio2, etc.
    audio.setAttribute("id", "audio" + i);
    audio.src = audioFile.audioFiles;

    // TODO Uncomment the below two lines if you need to put the audio tag on the DOM.
    // audio.hidden = true;
    // div.appendChild(audio);

    // create button as before
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    // Instead of creating an inner loop, use the same i from line 10
    button.setAttribute("id", "button"+i);

    // textContent eliminates the need for the separate textNode
    button.textContent = audioFile.alphabet;

    // click handler can go here.
    $(button).on("click", function () {

      audio.play();

    });

    div.appendChild(button); // Button added here works

    //create links
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    // link given text so you can see it.
    a.textContent = "Download";
    // dot notation property access is much cleaner
    a.href = audioFile.audioFiles;

    div.appendChild(a); // put a inside the div

    audio.className = "pronunciation";
}

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, and explaining where I went wrong! I am new to coding and I have been struggling with it for days. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays to concat strings and interpolate template literals to build each url. Then assign a `data-*` attribute with the corresponding url to each button. Details are commented in the demo.

---

### [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/K2YgMyROF4SMsdXX)

### Demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  html,
  body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font: 900 16px/1 Verdana;
  }
  .playlist {
    list-style: none;
  }
  
  li {
    margin: 5px;
  }
  
  button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 4rem;
    height: 2rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 3px ridge navy;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px 3px 6px;
    background: rgba(145, 201, 247, 0.2);
    color: navy;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  
  button:hover,
  button:active,
  button.active {
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background: rgba(145, 201, 247, 0.9);
  }   
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <ul class='playlist'></ul>
  </main>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Host
const base = `http://www.student.city.ac.uk/~aczd144/Audio-files/`;

// Generate an Array of letter pairs of an uppercase and lowercase
let AZaz = Array.from(Array(26).keys(), idx => String.fromCharCode(idx + 65) + String.fromCharCode(idx + 97));

// Generate an Array of file names
let file = Array.from(Array(26).keys(), idx => String.fromCharCode(idx + 97) + '.mp3');

// Add the non-standard letters to each Array
AZaz.push('&#197;&#229;');
AZaz.push('&#198;&#230;');
AZaz.push('&#216;&#248;');
file.push('aa.mp3');
file.push('ae.mp3');
file.push('Q%20(1).mp3');

// On each iteration add a <li> and <button> and interpolate the the data from both Arrays
for (let i = 0; i < AZaz.length; i++) {

  $('.playlist').append(`<li><button class="btn" type="button" data-key="${base+file[i]}">${AZaz[i]}</button></li>`);

}

// Create an Audio Object
const player = new Audio();

/*
Register the click event to .playlist 
e.target is the currently clicked button
Extract the data-key value and assign it to the Audio src attribute
Load the Audio
Call the playMedia function
*/
$('.playlist').on('click', '.btn', playAudio);

function playAudio(e) {
  $('.btn').removeClass('active');
  const tgt = $(e.target);
  const url = tgt.data('key');
  tgt.addClass('active');
  player.src = url;
  player.load();
  playMedia();
}

/*
Because Chrome is trying to stifle autoplay, the process of playing audio and 
video require a Promise
*/
async function playMedia() {
  try {
    await player.play();
  } catch (err) {}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```